W32dasm vs iDA pro- What im missing "string references"
I am a total beginner doing RE and have been learning a lot thanks to this community, and I want to thank you. I already looked for something similar in the other questions, but I don't know if it is because of my lack of knowledge or something different that I couldn't find.
So basically I'm doing an exercise that the goal is to find the references by looking at the strings("the instructor called black wizard") based on the error code, so when I open with win32dasm and search for the error string "Registration failed" the wind32dasm found the reference "00413c7f" without problem that's how it looks like:

So all good at this point, the problem is when I try it to open with IDA and search for the string:

As you can see the string references are missing my question is why, What am I missing? I have been reading about encoding options because that's my best guess but yeah... I could not find the answer yet so yeah, some ideas here about how to do these in IDA??.
